# How to catkin_package to bloom Debian library packages?

Tags: ros2, catkin, debian, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How does one configure a `catkin_package` such that, when bloomed, it produces a Debian library pair? More exactly, for some declared `catkin_package` as part of the `foobar` project, I want...

- a `ros-kinetic-foobar` containing `./opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfoobar.so`
- a `ros-kinetic-foobar-dev` containing `./opt/ros/kinetic/include/foobar/foobar.h`

...with the latter dependent on the former.

References:

- https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#run-time-shared-libraries
- https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#development-files

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313419/how-to-catkin_package-to-bloom-debian-library-packages?/) by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS buildfarm / bloom does not support auto-magic splitting of Debian packages into dev and non-dev packages. When you release a package `foo` with the ROS release pipeline you will get a single Debian package named `ros-<distro>-foo`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-01-22**:
shucks; is there room in the bloom code for such a feature? Is anyone else asking for this?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-01-22**:
I would expect something like to work generically to be fairly complicated. Feel free to create a ticket in https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom to start a discussion about it.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-01-23**:
There's been a few thread on it such as https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/20 and  https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/32 The main problem is that it can't really be done automatically and as such requires the maintainers to build up more metadata.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-01-23**:
Also doing this across multiple target platforms make this more complicated too.